# Erro ao instalar o Jeet Grid System

Tags: css, svn, grid

Estou tendo um problema para instalar o `Jeet Grid System`.

Quando eu dou um `svn checkout https://github.com/mojotech/jeet/trunk/scss/jeet` o console dá um erro:

`'svn' não é reconhecido como um comando interno ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.`

Alguém sabe como resolver?

Comment: Você precisa ter instalado o SVN antes de utilizar o comando. Recomendo que instale-o utilizando o NPM.

Comment: natan, na verdade eu já tinha o svn, mas pelo terminal ñ estava dando certo. A solução foi entrar na pasta do projeto, clicar com o botão direito e dar um 'SVN checkout'. =D